# Lighning : Override new button to autopopulate fields in new record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, button-overrides, new, s-control

since we are migrating to Lightning, I am experiencing some issues with a functionnality that we have. 
What I need is when i click New, the Name is auto populated for example with 'System'( this is used  on the save, System is replaced by a number according to the type etc)

Before, we have overriden the new button for several object with a scontrol, that concatenate to the URL Name=System.
That s-control was used on several object.

Now with Lightning, s-control are not supported, and also looks like the new record page is only in a modal.

I was thinking to use a lightning component, but New button is not yet supported for lightning component. Also how the prepopulate the Name field? 
I was thinking of a visual force page that redirects to a lightning component but how to prepopulate the Name field? That also means that I need to create a VF page for each object.

The workaroung i found is maybe a global action, and a predefined value for Name, but if possible I have really wanted to use the new button on the objects... The layout for each global action is limited and redirection too.

If anybody have faced a similar issues, I would be happy to see

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, Lightning quick action is the straight forward approach. If you don't mind adding some technical weight you have two alternative solutions:

1. You can create an action that calls on an intermediary Visual force page that will then redirect the user to the relevant record. This can cause issues in Salesforce1 as visualforce pages and lightning records exist in different domains.
2. Create a component to capture the data or just to redirect the user to the relevant record.
3. Create a lightning event that will redirect you to the new record, provided you can offer it some trigger point for the same in the record that you're viewing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Balanarayan.

I am pretty new to lightning, so just a clarification :

You say there is two alternatives solutions, is the points 2 and 3 are linked?

for 2, when you say the component capture the date, so the component is called when click on New, we fill the fields and click save ? for 3, that trigger event is for redirection and the prepopulation before the save, or just the redirection?

Thank you again for your help